# Would the MVVM pattern be appropriate for this application's requirements?

Tags: c#, wpf, model-view-controller, mvvm

I am just about to start building a large application which will perform different methods of string encryption on text files.

This is going to end up being a fairly large application so I'd like to be sure that the design I have is good from the beginning. I have taken a look at the Model-View-View Model design pattern however since there will be no data being passed back to the view I don't think that this is the best pattern to use.

The purpose of the application is literally to just perform a string encryption method on arbitrary text files and then display a message box that will only give a standard success or failure message based on whether the process succeeded or not.

Is MVC a more appropriate pattern here? I know that this is fairly uncommon and that MVVM seems to be the pattern of choice but, again, I feel that since no data is being passed back to the view that MVVM is inappropriate.

The interface for this application will only be a few text boxes which are used to select the encryption method and a button that, when clicked, will perform the appropriate encryption method.

Comment: You could just do that with straight up WPF or even a console application.

Comment: Edited the question, maybe you can move it to a more appropriate place such as http://programmers.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Welcome to StackOverflow !* I'll try to answer your 1st question as best as I can :D

From what I've read, I was about to rush on the keyboard and just tell you : *"Yes, go for broake"* but instead I've decided to craft you a really a small example of what benefits the MVVM pattern can bring to you.

Personally I was feeling a bit like you before, skeptical of the benefits and extra work it might incur; but let me tell you that it's really worth it. It's only recently that I've adopted the pattern and I can't stop thinking why haven't I done it before ? It's such a time-saver, keeps concerns separated and is really *simple*.

**So here's the example !**

[image]

**Now the MVVM pattern**

Here the diagram of how components communicates, notice that it's a chain :

*View <-> ViewModel <-> Model*

(you'll soon get the benefits of that)

**The Model:** it's the core of what your application does, for this example that's the componenent that encrypts data. This is your low-level class that deals with the encryption process, it does not have to know about the ViewModel nor the View. Its only concern is encrypting input data and outputting it, nothing else !

```
public class EncryptorModel
{
    public string Cipher(string text)
    {
        char[] enumerable = text.Select(s => ++s).ToArray();
        var cipher = new string(enumerable);
        return cipher;
    }
}
```

**The ViewModel (the view of your model):** now it's getting interesting, while the benefits of this component are not obvious at first sight, they are effectively present and I'll try to sell them to you :D

See the ViewModel as a gateway between the View and the Model, its job is to serve the requests coming from the View (the user), by executing operations on the Model and returning results sent by the Model back to the View.

As you can see below : it hosts properties for this ciphering example; passes data from View to/from Model (automatically thanks to WPF data-binding). Finally, it hosts  commands that the View triggers.

```
public class EncryptorViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private RelayCommand _cipher;
    private string _inputText;
    private string _outputText;

    public EncryptorViewModel()
    {
        Model = new EncryptorModel();
    }

    private EncryptorModel Model { get; set; }

    #region Public properties

    public string InputText
    {
        get { return _inputText; }
        set
        {
            _inputText = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
            Cipher.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }

    public string OutputText
    {
        get { return _outputText; }
        set
        {
            _outputText = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Commands

    public RelayCommand Cipher
    {
        get { return _cipher ?? (_cipher = new RelayCommand(CipherExecute, CipherCanExecute)); }
    }

    private void CipherExecute()
    {
        OutputText = Model.Cipher(InputText);
    }

    private bool CipherCanExecute()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(InputText);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**The View:** not much to say except that it presents your application and calls commands in the ViewModel.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.EncryptorView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="EncryptorView"
        Width="165"
        Height="188">
    <Window.Resources>
        <wpfApplication1:EncryptorViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Input text" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding InputText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            <TextBlock Text="Output text" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding OutputText}" />
            <Button Command="{Binding Cipher}" Content="Cipher" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### Conclusion

I could and have gone on a lengthier answer but cancelled in favor of staying simple, what you should retain for now :

- the View just binds to properties that the user needs to see/manipulate and binds to commands the user needs to perform on the Model
- the ViewModel represents a simplified view of the Model, it shows only what the View needs and performs commands on the Model
- the Model is strictly your professional field, it's job is to encrypt/decrypt, nothing else !

**Final conclusion :** concerns remains separated using MVVM, applications using this pattern are easy to maintain. It has not been obvious to me unless I spent 3 days with MVVM so I can only encourage you to do so, your programming projects will clearly benefit from that.

**Environment used:**

I've used Galasoft MVVM Light : http://www.mvvmlight.net/installing/nuget/

(the *MVVM Light libraries only* package)

I have voluntarily omitted the service locator part, you will find it in the Visual Studio project templates here : http://www.mvvmlight.net/installing

### EDIT

### Here are a few scenarios that upgrades the 'initial' scenario.

**Multiple ViewModels:**

Rule is to have one ViewModel per View (or user interface), so if your app. has 2 windows then you'll have 2 ViewModel.

**Share a Model between 2 or more ViewModels:**

If for instance you can certify that both windows can work on the same Model then you can only have 1 Model and you would declare it in `App.xaml` instead :

App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:wpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             StartupUri="EncryptorView.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <wpfApplication1:EncryptorModel x:Key="Model1"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

EncryptorViewModel1:

```
public class EncryptorViewModel1 : ViewModelBase
{
    //private EncryptorModel Model { get; set; }

    public EncryptorViewMode1l()
    {
        // Model = new EncryptorModel();

        // Now you retrieve the model in App.xaml instead of declaring a private one above
        var model =(EncryptorModel) Application.Current.FindResource("Model1");
    }
}
```

**Scenario : using multiple encryptors in the same View**

Here's another small example that shows you how to let the user choose an encryption method within the same View.

[image] [image]

We take the same ViewModel,

- we add `AvailableEncryptors` and `CurrentEncryptor` properties
- we modify `CipherCanExecute` so it that it takes into account the `CurrentEncryptor`, the user will be able to encrypt only when `InputText` is set and an encryptor is selected
- also `CipherExecute` is changed a bit, the `EncryptorModel` ciphers according specified string and encryptor

Updated ViewModel:

```
public class EncryptorViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private RelayCommand _cipher;
    private IEncryptor _currentEncryptor;
    private string _inputText;
    private string _outputText;

    public EncryptorViewModel()
    {
        Model = new EncryptorModel();
    }

    private EncryptorModel Model { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<IEncryptor> AvailableEncryptors
    {
        get
        {
            Type type = typeof (IEncryptor);
            IEnumerable<IEncryptor> encryptors =
                Assembly
                    .GetExecutingAssembly()
                    .GetTypes()
                    .Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p) && !p.IsInterface && !p.IsAbstract)
                    .Select(s => (IEncryptor) Activator.CreateInstance(s));
            return encryptors;
        }
    }

    public IEncryptor CurrentEncryptor
    {
        get { return _currentEncryptor; }
        set
        {
            _currentEncryptor = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
            Cipher.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }

    #region Public properties

    public string InputText
    {
        get { return _inputText; }
        set
        {
            _inputText = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
            Cipher.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }

    public string OutputText
    {
        get { return _outputText; }
        set
        {
            _outputText = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Commands

    public RelayCommand Cipher
    {
        get { return _cipher ?? (_cipher = new RelayCommand(CipherExecute, CipherCanExecute)); }
    }

    private void CipherExecute()
    {
        OutputText = Model.Cipher(CurrentEncryptor, InputText);
    }

    private bool CipherCanExecute()
    {
        return CurrentEncryptor != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(InputText);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**Note:** you might be tempted to entirely remove the Model and do everything inside the ViewModel but do not, even though the ViewModel just acts as a gateway and nothing more you should take the opportunity of implementing encryption-related logic in the Model rather than the ViewModel.

If you keep things separated you will potentially save a lot of time in the future, for instance, if you need a command-line version of your application you will just need to use the Model as all the logic necessary is there and not scattered through it and the ViewModel. (see the ViewModel being tied to a particular UI framework such as WPF)

Then I updated the Model to call an encryptor whenever we want it to encrypt something:

```
public class EncryptorModel
{
    public string Cipher(IEncryptor encryptor, string text)
    {
        return encryptor.Cipher(text);
    }
}
```

Finally, I've implemented encryptors:

```
public interface IEncryptor
{
    string Description { get; }
    string Cipher(string text);
}

public class Encryptor1 : IEncryptor
{
    #region IEncryptor Members

    public string Description
    {
        get { return "Encryptor 1"; }
    }

    public string Cipher(string text)
    {
        char[] enumerable = text.Select(s => ++s).ToArray();
        var cipher = new string(enumerable);
        return cipher;
    }

    #endregion
}

public class Encryptor2 : IEncryptor
{
    #region IEncryptor Members

    public string Description
    {
        get { return "Encryptor 2"; }
    }

    public string Cipher(string text)
    {
        char[] enumerable = text.Select(s => --s).ToArray();
        var cipher = new string(enumerable);
        return cipher;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And the updated view:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.EncryptorView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="EncryptorView"
        Width="165"
        Height="188">
    <Window.Resources>
        <wpfApplication1:EncryptorViewModel x:Key="ModelView" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ModelView}}">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Select an encryptor" />
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableEncryptors}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentEncryptor}">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="wpfApplication1:IEncryptor">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
            <TextBlock Text="Input text" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding InputText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            <TextBlock Text="Output text" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding OutputText}" />
            <Button Command="{Binding Cipher}" Content="Cipher" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Conclusion**

So as you can see, I've struggled a bit implementing new types but it pays off, each encryption method is independent, the encryptor as well which is good. After all, an encryptor is not an encryption method so they are better off separated.

Comment: +1. +10 if I could for an excellent, detailed, comprehensive answer, which is also *correct*. No MVVM means definitely more effort in WPF regardless of the type of project you're talking about.

Comment: This is a seriously excellent answer, I really appreciate the time you've taken to answer this!  Just a final question, if there is no data to return to the view do I just have no properties in the view model?

Comment: Great, thanks! Yes, if you don't want to return data then don't implement any property. As you can see some people are unhappy with your question and would like to close it ... While it's a good question it is true that it should be reformulated to fit the site; I'll try to reformulate it to keep it open.

Comment: Thanks again for all your help.  Do you think that it would be best to have a view model for each of the string encryption methods?

Comment: See my edit, I have put a few scenarios that you might be interested in.